# Excel does not import Guids (Unique Identifiers) when importing data using the "External Data" feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, external-data

When I try to use Excel 2013 to import External Data from a SQL Server Data Source, it does not import the Guids.

The Query I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
```

The table Structure is:

```
ThingId uniqueidentifier,
ThingName nvarchar(50)
```

When I explicitly ask Excel to import just the `uniqueidentifier`, it imports nothing (query):

```
SELECT ThingId from TABLENAME
```

How do I get Excel to import Unique Identifiers (GUIDs) when I use the "External Data" feature?

Answer (score 3):

Excel (for reasons I have not yet determined), cannot handle imported Guids natively.  In order to import GUIDs from SQL Server, you must first change the query to CAST the Guid to an `nvarchar`.  The data source query would change to:

```
SELECT CAST(ThingID as nvarchar(100)), ThingName from TABLENAME
```

The `CAST` function ensures that the GUID is in a format that Excel interprets as text.  Any format that outputs text will do; it doesn't have to be `nvarchar`.

Comment: I wonder if that's generally true of columns that are stored as byte arrays. You probably can't import binary or varbinary columns either.