# Error when trying to get data from SQL to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I'm have an issue with Excel reading UniqueIdentifier columns from a SQL Database.

In excel, I go to DATA > GET DATA > FROM DATABASE > FROM SQL DATABASE. Login and connect to the sql database just fine. I can see my tables and when I click on a certain tables I get this error below:

```
 DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    DataSourcePath=odin\act7;gfpact
    Message=Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
    Number=8169
    Class=16
```

But I can select other tables just fine with the same GUID format.

I did a CREATE TO > New QUERY so you can the table properties

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_COMPANY](
    [COMPANYID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [CATEGORY] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [REFERREDBY] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [TICKERSYMBOL] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [NUMEMPLOYEES] [int] NULL,
    [INDUSTRY] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [SICCODE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [REVENUE] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [TERRITORY] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [REGION] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [DIVISION] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [WEBADDRESS] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [HIERLEVEL] [int] NULL,
    [HIERPATH] [varchar](556) NULL,
    [HASSUBCOMPANY] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CONTACTQUERYTEXT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OPPQUERYTEXT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [QUERYVERSIONID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PARENTCOMPANYID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ISPRIVATE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MANAGEUSERID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CREATEUSERID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CREATEDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EDITUSERID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [EDITDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [IMPORTDATE] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [TBL_COMPANY_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [COMPANYID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How can I get Excel to read these UniqueIdentifier columns?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Excel does not import Guids (Unique Identifiers) when importing data using the “External Data” feature](https://superuser.com/questions/833261/excel-does-not-import-guids-unique-identifiers-when-importing-data-using-the)

Comment: I think you should use Stored procedure so that Uniqueidentifier should be NNVARCHAR data type CAST also to assign Uidentifier!

Comment: I think you should use Stored procedure so that Uniqueidentifier should be NVARCHAR data type CAST also to assign Uidentifier!